# What does the then() method do in REST-assured?

Tags: java, javadoc, rest-assured

I'm looking for a formal definition of what the then() method does in the REST-assured API and can't find a method explanation in the javadocs. What does it do?

Reference:
http://static.javadoc.io/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.0.7/io/restassured/RestAssured.html

Comment: `then` return a promise: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: See http://static.javadoc.io/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.0.7/io/restassured/response/Validatable.html#then--, but check the generic types which are used (like from the `Response` class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get returns a `Response` object: http://static.javadoc.io/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.0.7/io/restassured/response/Response.html

Response inherits the following interfaces: ResponseBody, ResponseBodyData, ResponseBodyExtractionOptions, ResponseOptions, **Validatable**

`then` is the only `Validatable` method: http://static.javadoc.io/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.0.7/io/restassured/response/Validatable.html

However, this drives the majority of the event-driven validation, through the use of ValidatableResponseOptions: http://static.javadoc.io/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.0.7/io/restassured/response/ValidatableResponseOptions.html

In a testing class, this allows you to write tests specifically geared towards validating your rest endpoints without having to do the relatively more messy unpacking of a RestResponse to evaluate individual parts of the response.